# Saving Cloud Text to Speech audio file to Cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

Hi I am trying to use google cloud text to speech with appengine. When I send API requests to the text to speech servers, I receive a response with an audio file attached. Now I am trying to write this file to my bucket. Here's my code:

```
def speak(translation, target_lang):
    lang_dict = {'ar': 'ar-XA', 'en': 'en-GB', 'cs': 'cs-CZ', 'da': 'da-DK', 'nl': 'nl-NL', 'fi': 'fi-FI', 'fr': 'fr-FR', 'de': 'de-DE', 'el': 'el-GR', 'hi': 'hi-IN', 'hu': 'hu-HU', 'id': 'id-ID', 'it': 'it-IT',
                 'ja': 'ja-JP', 'ko': 'ko-KR', 'zh': 'cmn-CN', 'no': 'nb-NO', 'pl': 'pl-PL', 'pt': 'pt-BR', 'ru': 'ru-RU', 'sk': 'sk-SK', 'es': 'es-ES', 'sv': 'sv-SE', 'tr': 'tr-TR', 'uk': 'uk-UA', 'vi': 'vi-VN'}
    lang_code = ''
    for key, val in lang_dict.items():
        if target_lang == key:
            lang_code = val
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=translation)
    voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code=lang_code,
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
    audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3)
    response = ttsClient.synthesize_speech(
        input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
    )
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("MY_BUCKET_NAME")
    blob = bucket.blob("output.mp3")
    blob.upload_from_file(response.audio_content)
    return " "
```

I have removed the actual bucket name from this code snippet but everything else is the same. Also, I tried just writing to the local file system instead of using buckets but appengine does not allow it.

### EDIT

Here's the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 80, in hello
    speak(translation[0], translation[1])
  File "/srv/main.py", line 59, in speak
    blob.upload_from_file(response.audio_content)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2343, in upload_from_file
    created_json = self._do_upload(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2180, in _do_upload
    response = self._do_resumable_upload(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2024, in _do_resumable_upload
    upload, transport = self._initiate_resumable_upload(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1911, in _initiate_resumable_upload
    upload.initiate(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 397, in initiate
    method, url, payload, headers = self._prepare_initiate_request(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py", line 463, in _prepare_initiate_request
    if stream.tell() != 0:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'"

Comment: The error seems to be due to the fact that you are reading a file, try to do this with a file. Also, while App Engine Standard shouldn't allow you to use the /tmp folder, App Engine Flex should.